# How to at a return value with double quote character enclosing it

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm working on C++ homework, where we are creating overloaded functions. The instructor wants the values to be enclosed in `""`s. I was able to accomplish that part, but he clarified that he wants the `""`s to be added before the `cout` statements in the `main()` function.

The code below operates and produces an output that is correct, except for the application of the double quotes. I'm lost as to how I would apply the double quotes in the overload function. I've tried a few different examples from Google, but not luck so far.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
    
using namespace std;
    
int iQuote(int);
double iQuote(double);
string iQuote(string);
        
int x = 4;
double y = 8.2;
string name = "Dan";
    
int main()
{
    cout << "The int argument is " << "\"" << iQuote(x) << "\"" << endl;
    cout << "The double argument is "<< "\"" << iQuote(y) << "\"" << endl;
    cout << "the string argument is " << "\"" << iQuote(name) << "\"" << endl;
    return 0;
}
    
int iQuote(int a){      
    return(a);
}
    
double iQuote(double a){
    return (string(a));
}
    
string iQuote(string a){
    return(a);
}
```

Comment: hey return is not a call to a method, so dont do ***return(a);***

Comment: *I've tried a few different examples from google* -- I'm curious as to what you've tried, since what you posted isn't really that close to what your assignment is stating.  What should the return type of `iQuote` be? Why are you returning `int` and `double`?  Aren't we talking about strings?  For example, it should be obvious that the `double iQuote` function is wrong, in that you are returning a `string`.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ `return(a)` is perfectly legal

Comment: All i need to do is get double quotes to go around the integers or strings in the iQuote function so that calling iQuote in the cout statement supplies the value with the quotes. Instead of how im applying the quotes now

Comment: @GusRobins you can't put quotes on `int`/`double` values, quotes only work on strings.

Comment: That should do it i was trying something similar but missed the to_string(). Thanks

Comment: Instead of `return(a);` you can do `return<%a%>;` for clarity.  And you may want to use [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function returns an `int`, `double`, etc then it CANT return values with quotes on them.  Quotes only work on strings. You would have to do something like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
using namespace std;
    
string iQuote(int);
string iQuote(double);
string iQuote(string);
        
int x = 4;
double y = 8.2;
string name = "Dan";
    
int main()
{
    cout << "The int argument is " << iQuote(x) << endl;
    cout << "The double argument is " << iQuote(y) << endl;
    cout << "the string argument is " << iQuote(name) << endl;
    return 0;
}

string iQuote(int a){
    return "\"" + to_string(a) + "\"";
    // or: return iQuote(to_string(a));
}

string iQuote(double a){
    return "\"" + to_string(a) + "\"";
    // or: return iQuote(to_string(a));
}

string iQuote(string a){
    return "\"" + a + "\"";
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, I apologize for my complete lack of knowledge c++ is all new for me first year Computer Information System student. I've only played around with python before now so most of this stuff is still like a foreign language to me. I'm sure you'll be seeing more questions from me on here. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @RemyLebeau's answer, if you want a generic way of returning a string, here is another method:

```
template <typename T>
string iQuote(T a){
    return "\"" + to_string(a) + "\"";
}

std::string iQuote(std::string a){
    return "\"" + a + "\"";
}
```

As long as the type passed to `iQuote` is compatible with [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), then you don't have to write separate functions for each of those types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string iQuote(T a){
    return "\"" + std::to_string(a) + "\"";
}

std::string iQuote(std::string a){
    return "\"" + a + "\"";
}

int x = 4;
double y = 8.2;
std::string name = "Dan";
float f = 4.9f;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The int argument is " << iQuote(x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The double argument is " << iQuote(y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the string argument is " << iQuote(name) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the float argument is " << iQuote(f) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The int argument is "4"
The double argument is "8.200000"
the string argument is "Dan"
the float argument is "4.900000"
```

---

Another generic way is to use [std::ostringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).  Then as long as the type has an overloaded `operator <<`, the value can be placed in quotes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string iQuote(T a){
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << "\"" << a << "\"";
    return s.str();
}

int x = 4;
double y = 8.2;
std::string name = "Dan";
float f = 4.9f;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The int argument is " << iQuote(x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The double argument is " << iQuote(y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the string argument is " << iQuote(name) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the float argument is " << iQuote(f) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The int argument is "4"
The double argument is "8.2"
the string argument is "Dan"
the float argument is "4.9"
```

The output is formatted differently -- this is due to the stream's default processing, as opposed to `to_string`.